# bash variable evaluation on command substitution

Tags: bash, command

Below is a piece of bash code

```
2 bar=false
3 foo=$(echo $bar);
4 echo $foo
5
6 echo change bar from false to true
7
8 bar=true
9 echo $foo
```

Below is output

```
false
change a from false to true
false
```

I was expecting  line 9 echo command gonna re-execute the command substitution and output true. However it is not. the second $foo would directly refer to "foo" value, which is literal "false", instead of doing command execution again. Well, that is reasonable to design like this. Am I guessing right ? Is there any behind-the-scene mechanism about this behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo=$(echo $bar);` is an assignement, not function that is re-evaluated when you later change the value of `bar`.

`foo` is just set here with the output of the command substitution and the value is `false`.

Comment: ok, I know.  I  just put   `foo=$(echo $bar)`  above line 9. It output true. So I shall re assign it by using "=". Thanks very much. BTW, how did you put newline in comment. I tried "enter". It just did the posting...

Comment: Also, it's better written as just `foo="${bar}"`. No reason to spawn a sub-shell just to assign a variable the value of a different variable.

Comment: @twalberg It was just for the need of demonstration here, but it's worth to be pointed out.